# AWS EC2 Apache User Cannot run php exec

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, exec

I am using the following PHP script to send an email from my server.  I need to send an email to the admin when a new record is created in the DB.  So within the same php script that updates the DB, I want to trigger the other script that sends the email.

Problem is no matter what I do, apache will not execute the email script when requested from the web/api.

However, when I run `php sendemail.php` from the command line it works.  Also when I run `php updatedb.php` which includes the `exec('php sendemail.php')` also works from the command line (these are all executed with root "ec2-user").

Things I tried:

1. I checked the disabled functions in php.ini and it is empty, nothing is disabled.
2. I tried changing file permissions to include 'x' for the apache group still no go.
3. I tried replacing `exec` with `shell_exec`, and `include`, no luck.

Here is 'sendemail.php':

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$SesClient = new SesClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'version' => '2010-12-01',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2'
]);

$sender_email = 'sender@example.com';
$recipient_emails = ['recipient1@example.com','recipient2@example.com'];

$configuration_set = 'ConfigSet';

$subject = 'Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for PHP)';
$plaintext_body = 'This email was sent with Amazon SES using the AWS SDK for PHP.' ;
$html_body =  '<h1>AWS Amazon Simple Email Service Test Email</h1>'.
              '<p>This email was sent with <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/ses/">'.
              'Amazon SES</a> using the <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/">'.
              'AWS SDK for PHP</a>.</p>';
$char_set = 'UTF-8';

try {
    $result = $SesClient->sendEmail([
        'Destination' => [
            'ToAddresses' => $recipient_emails,
        ],
        'ReplyToAddresses' => [$sender_email],
        'Source' => $sender_email,
        'Message' => [
          'Body' => [
              'Html' => [
                  'Charset' => $char_set,
                  'Data' => $html_body,
              ],
              'Text' => [
                  'Charset' => $char_set,
                  'Data' => $plaintext_body,
              ],
          ],
          'Subject' => [
              'Charset' => $char_set,
              'Data' => $subject,
          ],
        ],
        'ConfigurationSetName' => $configuration_set,
    ]);
    $messageId = $result['MessageId'];
    echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // output error message if fails
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo("The email was not sent. Error message: ".$e->getAwsErrorMessage()."\n");
    echo "\n";
}
```

a short version of the updatedb.php file, omitting all transactions:

```
<?php
    exec('php send_email.php', $sendEmail);
    require_once 'response.php';
    $response = new response();
    $response->setHttpStatusCode(201);
    $response->setSuccess(true);
    $response->addMessage('DB Record Inserted successfully ::: ');
    $response->setData($sendEmail);
    $response->send();
?>
```

in the `updatedb.php` file, if I change the first line to `echo exec('whoami')` and hit it from the web it works.  Which is what I am looking for exactly except that I want to work for `php sendemail.php`

Environment: AWS EC2 Amazon Linux 2 AMI.  PHP 7.2.34

I hope it is clear.  I am beginner with linux.  Please help.  Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: You case is missing permissions for `apache` user. You need to define, what permissions to be given to `sendemail.php`. If you give execute permission to the whole world, `apache` won't have any issues executing it. Or you give the file to `apache` group(needs to check permission of the whole tree and not just the file), your problem will be resolved. By the way, when you change the permissions you can try to check it with `sudo -u apache php sendemail.php` instead of running other scripts. If this worked, your issue is resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much @Riz your tip about `sudo -u apache php sendemail.php` saved my day!  I was able to debug on the command line and it turns out that my mistake was with the line `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` in my original `sendemail.php` script I was requiring the file from a directory that did not belong to the `apache` group.  So, once I moved the vendor folder to the same folder as the `sendemail.php` script file everything worked great!

Lesson learned: Make sure all required/included files belong to the `apache` group.  There was no need to grant apache any execution permissions on any file.

Comment: I am glad you were able to resolve your issue. Giving extra permissions to apache isn't a good idea and one should only give temporary permissions to troubleshoot. I forgot to mention that above in the comment.